# Getting error While using Ajax Extenders

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using Ajax dropdown extender on a button. But Getting a Runtime error

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

It Occuer when compiler try to compile extenderbase class. The code of eror in class is

```
  link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                header.Controls.Add(link);

 //here i am getting the error            -->   // ASP.NET AJAX doesn't currently send a new head element down during an async postback,
                // so we do the same thing on the client by registering the appropriate script for after
                // the update.
```

What should I try to remove the Error.also I change the ajax toolkit version but that didn't work,I change <%=%> to<@#%> in master page but that als didn't work. I am using visual web developer 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the format <%#.....   %> in your markup and then in your Page_Load method in codebehind put this line

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks @abide I forget this in last script of master page